# Is it possible to stream a video with flutter camera plugin?

Tags: camera, dart, video-streaming, flutter

I've been playing around with the camera plugin, I know there's the possibility to capture a video via the `CameraController` with the functions  `start/stopVideoRecording`, the functions will take a path for a file as an input.

I'd like to be able to stream this video to a server while it's being recorded, is it possible somehow with the current capabilities of the camera plugin?

Comment: Don't think so. You can create a feature request in the Flutter GitHub repo.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can we record video on flutter web?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like it is possible as it was done at Flutter Live with one of the development demos. Check out the [YouTube video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAEWySye0BQ) . at 24:17.  There is a method on the CameraController called getByteStream. The gist of the method shown below.

```
void cameraBytesToDetector({@required CameraController camera}){
  camera.startByteStream( (image) {
    // do something with the image stream here
  });
}
```

But I can find no reference anywhere as I am also looking for a way to read the video stream.

Comment: It looks like the change hasn't been merged yet. Check out this pull request: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/965. The author is the same person from the video

Comment: This was never merged?

Comment: It was merged jan 2019

Comment: In the end, `startByteStream` was renamed to `startCameraStream`, so no audio is provided.

Comment: I am looking solution of Stream Screen Recording in flutter, is there any suggestion?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can call Java/Kotlin or Objective-C/Swift libraries from Dart.

I can suggest that libraries for Android,

https://github.com/begeekmyfriend/yasea

https://github.com/ant-media/LiveVideoBroadcaster

The only thing that you have to do is developing a dart interface to this kind of libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The `startByteStream` feature mentioned by Steve was not actually added to the plugin, because it was only called `startByteStream` initially, but actually only provided images. As a result, during development, this function was renamed to `startImageStream`, as seen in this [commit](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/965/commits/615562056e0cebc9eb022b98344cc7f5cce187dd). So there is a `startImageStream`, and you can send over image frames as soon as you get it over web-rtc to your backend. Then, you can try record the audio separately and send it over too.

However, `startImageStream` does not include any audio, and may not be performant. There is an open issue for adding byte streaming capability, including audio. [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55955)

As of now, `startByteStream` does not exist in the [code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/lib/camera.dart).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question but there is a package called **agora_rtc_engine** that can do this.

Comment: Only for agora.io streams.