# Flutter: How to stream live audio provided by a http url without mp3 extension

Tags: flutter

How to stream live audio provided by a http url without mp3 extension with flutter?
it's not a remote file, 
but a streaming url like a webradio

Answer (score 2):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/url_audio_stream 
github https://github.com/tcronis/url_audio_stream

code snippet

```
AudioStream stream = new AudioStream("https://your_url_goes_here.com");
stream.start();
stream.pause();
stream.resume();
stream.stop();
```

full example code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:url_audio_stream/url_audio_stream.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _platformVersion = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  static AudioStream stream = new AudioStream("your url");
  Future<void> callAudio(String action) async{
    if(action == "start"){
      stream.start();
    }else if(action == "stop"){
      stream.stop();
    }else if(action == "pause"){
      stream.pause();
    }else{
      stream.resume();
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new RaisedButton(
                child: new Text("Start"),
                onPressed: (){
                  callAudio("start");
                },
              ),
              new RaisedButton(
                child: new Text("Stop"),
                onPressed: (){
                  callAudio("stop");
                },
              ),
              new RaisedButton(
                child: new Text("Pause"),
                onPressed: (){
                  callAudio("pause");
                },
              ),
              new RaisedButton(
                child: new Text("Resume"),
                onPressed: (){
                  callAudio("resume");
                },
              )
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please be aware this solution's package is discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

It's working but for some url i need to make some change in the AndroidManifest.xml to make it working.

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Answer (score 0):

Check working example here with WebRadio Urls.
[Link to Repo](https://cutt.ly/flutter-radio)

[image: Watch the video]